# TeeChart Line Drawing by giving String values to both x-axis And y-axis

Tags: android, teechart

I'm using TeeChartJavaAndroid_3.2012.0202 and i didn't be able to draw line that has String values in both X and Y axis. Is this possible ??
Knowing that line.add() method doesn't take 2 String  values !?!?

Answer (score 1):

The add() overrides only support double, int, float, DateTime, and arrays of the mentioned for the X and Y values. You can add an String as an argument on some of the overrides to be taken as the point Label. Then, this string will be used in the mandatory axis to highlight the point (if the axis label style is set to Auto or Mark).

If you are looking for an override of the add() method taking XValue, YValue, XLabel and YLabel; being XLabel and YLabel the strings to be represented in the horizontal and vertical axes labels, I'm afraid this isn't supported at the moment. However, you could use the add() override that takes one string to be drawn in the mandatory axis and use the axis getlabel event to format the non-mandatory axis labels.